# Quadric question

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

I'm trying to prove that given 3 disjoint lines in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ there exists a non-singular quadric containing them. The exercise is from the following link:

http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/abenito/varios/ReidAlgebraicGeometry.pdf

I think you have to use page 19 of the source and make an argument based on dimension, but I'm really not sure. Any hint/help appreciated.

Comment: Hint: a quadric in P^3 has 10 coefficients. To contain a given line imposes 3 conditions.

Comment: To flesh out the hint: $10-3 \cdot 3 = 1>0$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Just to be sure, your $1$ is an "affine" $1$, right? I mean, *the* wanted quadric should be the point $\mathbb P(V)$, where $V$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Dear @Brenin: yes, my 1 is the dimension of the space of _forms_ that vanish on the 3 lines.